# A list with two variables

Tags: java, list, loops

I'd like to build a map algorithm and do the following thing:

First, create all points on the map.

Already given which points are connected and the length between them (as integers).

Now the problem is to find the shortest connection between them.

Therefore what I will do is to create an object of each point that contains a list of all the points this particular point is connected to and the length from the original point to that point.

An example would be:

From A to g there is a distance of 7

From A to c there is a distance of 3

Where A is connected to c and A is connected to g

My problem is that if I use HashMap I have some problems finding out whether or not the points are connected because HashMap is not easy to loop through is there an easier way to do this or is there an alternative to HashMap?

Comment: smells like linkedhashmap, huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Prim's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) and [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)

If you have a set of vertices(a point in your case), and weights of the paths between them(distance in your case) its MST gives only the paths which connect all of the vertices and have the total sum of the distances minimum.

Prim's Algorithm and Dijkstra's Algorithm can be used to find the MST.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do but im still looking for a list to contain my number and name of the vertex

Comment: You just need an n*n distance matrix (n is the number of points) which has the distance between the points. And you can make another array of size n to store the name of your points.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for implementation of [Djikstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (finding the shortest path on weighted graph).

I think that the [solution](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html) here fits the bill

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about looping through a HashMap: you are supposed to use an iterator to do it for you:

```
HashMap hmap = new HashMap();
hmap.put("a", "hello world!");
hmap.put("b", "goodbye!");
hmap.put("c", 42);
Set s = hmap.entrySet();
Iterator i = s.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
}
```

Comment: i am really glad for everyones response however its a problem i would like to solve my self so hashmap is the best list to use for this purpose?

Comment: I would recommend learning the graph algorithms, but if you'd like to solve it first using your own method, HashMap will be fine.